# sizing of trace of pcb?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

Dose any one have example (picture) of real pcb board of various size traces .like 40th 60th....etc.actually i designed pcb on software as my term assignment .but i want to which width looks like how in real life ..i have also seen 3d simulation but i'm not satisfy with that .so that i want to see a real life example  like a picture of a pcb .If any one have any example then please give it to me .it will help me a lot